# Accidentally deleted a configuration file in spring app, can you find this file in GitHub commit?

Tags: intellij-idea

My 1 year old has just leaned on my laptop as I was typing and a popup flashed up saying delete 1 item just as I clicked ENTER. I don't have a clue what it deleted but it wouldn't let me undo whatever happened (Using IntelliJ) When I tried starting the app again it wouldn't load and gave me an error about being unable to authenticate database login details. I think I have narrowed it down to it deleting the configuration file. I tried to revert to my previous GitHub commit, but still had the same error.

I have reinput the database environment variables in my configuration file for `DATABASE_USERNAME` and `DATABASE_PASSWORD` and I can start the application up again now.

Is there any way to find out on GitHub if the prev config file contained anything other settings? I made this app about 18 months ago and don't have a clue if I added anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new file with the same name and check the local history in intellij? I am not sure for how long intellij keeps track of deleted files, but i tried it and it worked for me

Comment: Hi, I don't even know what the file name would have been? I am guessing IntelliJ saves the config file somewhere, but not sure what it would have been called